# C# recursive function

Tags: c#, recursion

THIS QUESTION IS ANSWERED!

I need to get all files from dropbox. But I cant finish my recursive function, it doesnt work, i have an idea why it doesnt work, but i dont know how to fix it

```
 private void getAllFiles(string path)
    {
        var dropCon = DatabaseDropbox.Instance();
        if (dropCon.IsConnect())
        {
            ICloudDirectoryEntry folder = dropCon.DropboxStorage.GetFolder(path);
            foreach (ICloudFileSystemEntry fsentry in folder)
            {
                if (fsentry is ICloudDirectoryEntry) // IF FOLDER
                {

                }
                else // IF FILE
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(path + " " + fsentry.Name);
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(fsentry.Name);
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(path);
                    listViewFolders.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
            }
            foreach (ICloudFileSystemEntry fsentry in folder)
            {
                if (fsentry is ICloudDirectoryEntry) // IF FOLDER
                {
                    var mpath = path + "/" + fsentry.Name;
                    getAllFiles(mpath);
                }
                else // IF FILE
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(path + " " + fsentry.Name);
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(fsentry.Name);
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(path);
                    listViewFolders.Items.Add(lvi);
                }         
            }
        }           

    }
```

If its finds file, it adds it to the list (C# form).

HOW IT DOESNT WORK:

It will list all files in the first directory, 
then it will go to the first folder found, lets call that folder "fol1".
After it scans all "fol1", it adds found files to the list, which is good. 
But then , when it should go back and search for more files in other directories , "fol2","fol3". Recursion just exists itself and it doesnt do that. So thats my problem.

```
FOUND RESULTS:
https://gyazo.com/fda8fde13dfbf32f35d39b87712b5751

ACTUAL FOLDERS:
https://gyazo.com/619e5c46bbc113d7d23a56b225f4f209
https://gyazo.com/265034521f317bf0d308910929d1664c
https://gyazo.com/ed9fe5375e1b21f54bbd1f127085c255
```

Thanks.

WORKING CODE :

```
private void getAllFiles(string path)
    {
        var dropCon = DatabaseDropbox.Instance();
        if (dropCon.IsConnect())
        {
            ICloudDirectoryEntry folder = dropCon.DropboxStorage.GetFolder(path);

            foreach (ICloudFileSystemEntry fsentry in folder)
            {
                if (fsentry is ICloudDirectoryEntry) // IF FOLDER
                {
                    var mpath = path + "/" + fsentry.Name;
                    getAllFiles(mpath);
                }
                else // IF FILE
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(path + " " + fsentry.Name);
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(fsentry.Name);
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(path);
                    listViewFolders.Items.Add(lvi);
                }         
            }
        }                   
    }
```

Comment: What's your idea of why it doesn't work?

Comment: Why it doesn't work ? And why does it return always true ?

Comment: We don't know what "it doesn't work" means. Please explain better the unexpected behavior your are facing.

Comment: Also, what doesn't work about it? How is what the above code does different than the expected behavior? "It doesn't work" could mean so many things.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code *and* accurately describe the problem.

Comment: For instance, stick in print statements to trace its execution.  At the top of the routine, print "ENTER" and the path you got.  Before returning, print a short message about what you return.  In between, print something about the data and control flow.

Comment: I added how it doesnt work.

Comment: Should you really be creating a new `dropCon` on each recursive call?

Comment: Also the issue is that you return at the first recursive call you make thus breaking out of the `foreach` loop.  It doesn't look like you really need a return type at all.  So change `return getAllFiles(mpath);` to `getAllFiles(mpath);`.

Comment: I know that I shouldn't. I was going to edit that later, but thats not the problem right know.

Comment: juharr, Yes! that was the problem, Thanks a lot!. That was pretty dumb error tho ;(. New to C#. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

```
private void getAllFiles(string path)
        {
            var dropCon = DatabaseDropbox.Instance();
            if (dropCon.IsConnect())
            {
                ICloudDirectoryEntry folder = dropCon.DropboxStorage.GetFolder(path);

                foreach (ICloudFileSystemEntry fsentry in folder)
                {
                    if (fsentry is ICloudDirectoryEntry) // IF FOLDER
                    {
                        var mpath = path + "/" + fsentry.Name;
                        getAllFiles(mpath);
                    }
                    else // IF FILE
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(path + " " + fsentry.Name);
                        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(fsentry.Name);
                        lvi.SubItems.Add(path);
                        listViewFolders.Items.Add(lvi);
                    }         
                }
            }                   
        }
```